# Svgmin infinite loop when running inside a task

Tags: svg, gulp

I'm trying to get svgmin to work in my gulpfile. This is my current config:

```
var gulp        = require('gulp');
var browserSync = require('browser-sync').create();
var sass        = require('gulp-sass');
var minify      = require('gulp-minify');
var uglify      = require('gulp-uglify');
var pump        = require('pump');
var concat      = require('gulp-concat');
var connect     = require('gulp-connect-php');
var svgmin      = require('gulp-svgmin');




// Static Server + watching scss/html files
gulp.task('serve', function() {

    connect.server({}, function (){
        browserSync.init({
          proxy: '127.0.0.1:8000'
        });
      });


    gulp.watch("assets/scss/*.scss", ['sass']);
    gulp.watch("assets/js/*.js", ['javascripts']);
    gulp.watch("assets/img/**/*.svg", ['svg']);
    gulp.watch('**/*.php').on('change', function () {
        browserSync.reload();
      });

});

// Optimize SVG

gulp.task('svg', function() {

    return gulp.src('assets/img/**/*.svg')
        .pipe(svgmin())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('assets/img/'));
    browserSync.reload();
});


// Compile sass into CSS & auto-inject into browsers
gulp.task('sass', function() {
    return gulp.src([
        "node_modules/normalize.css/normalize.css",
        'node_modules/animate.css/animate.min.css',
        "assets/scss/main.scss"
        ])
        .pipe(sass().on('error', sass.logError))
        .pipe(minify())
        .pipe(concat('main.css'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest("assets/build"))
        .pipe(browserSync.stream());
});


// Compile javascripts & refresh browser
gulp.task('javascripts', function (cb) {
  pump([
        gulp.src([
            // Javascript files we need
            'assets/js/modernizr.js', // Modernizr
            'node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js', // jQuery
            'node_modules/gsap/src/minified/TweenMax.min.js', // GSAP Aninmations
            'node_modules/scrollmagic/scrollmagic/uncompressed/ScrollMagic.js', // ScrollMagic Main
            'node_modules/scrollmagic/scrollmagic/uncompressed/plugins/animation.gsap.js', // GASP ScrollMagic plugin

            'assets/js/main.js' // Main JS file
        ]),
        concat('main.js'),
        uglify(),
        gulp.dest('assets/build'),
    ],
    cb
  );
  browserSync.reload();
});


gulp.task('default', ['sass', 'svg', 'javascripts', 'serve']);
```

When I run `gulp svg` it runs correctly without any errors. But when I run `gulp` (and thus the `serve` task) the `svg` task ends in a infinite loop. What am I doing wrong here? I want my gulp to minify my SVG files whenever theres a new file or a change, and then update the browser with browerSync.

```
[15:46:09] Starting 'svg'...
[15:46:10] Finished 'svg' after 823 ms
[15:46:10] Starting 'svg'...
[15:46:11] Finished 'svg' after 609 ms
[15:46:11] Starting 'svg'...
[15:46:11] Finished 'svg' after 618 ms
[15:46:11] Starting 'svg'...
[15:46:12] Finished 'svg' after 630 ms
[15:46:12] Starting 'svg'...
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your problem originates with this watch:

```
gulp.watch("assets/img/**/*.svg", ['svg']);
```

This runs the `svg` task whenever an SVG file is touched. In your `svg` task you do the following:

```
return gulp.src('assets/img/**/*.svg')
  .pipe(svgmin())
  .pipe(gulp.dest('assets/img/'));
```

This minifies all your SVG files and replaces each file with its minified version. So what happens is:

- `svg` task is run
- all SVG files are replaced with their minified version
- watch is triggered, because SVG files have been touched
- `svg` task is run
- all SVG files are replaced with their minified version
- watch is triggered, because SVG files have been touched
- etc ...

You need to break that cycle.

One way of doing that is to just place the minified SVG files into the `assets/build` directory as you do with files in your other tasks:

```
return gulp.src('assets/img/**/*.svg')
  .pipe(svgmin())
  .pipe(gulp.dest('assets/build/'));
```

If you really want to replace the SVG files your can use the [`gulp-cached` plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-cached). It prevents the SVG files from being overwritten if there are no actual content changes:

```
var cache = require('gulp-cached');

gulp.task('svg', function() {
  return gulp.src('assets/img/**/*.svg')
    .pipe(cache('svgmin'))
    .pipe(svgmin())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('assets/img/'))
    .pipe(browserSync.stream());
});
```

This has the added benefit that your `svg` task will run faster, since only modified files will need to be processed now.

Comment: In addition to what @Sven said, your gulp.task('default', ['sass', 'svg', 'javascripts', 'serve']);  doesn't need anything besides 'serve' in it.  'serve' will run the other three tasks when they change.